# ExtJs 4.2 Store issue with rawData

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I am calling store , but while i print its data it says `undefined`

```
var store1 = Ext.create('Store1', {storeId: 'headerId'}).load({
     params: {
        gridFlag: 'gridHeader'
    }
});
   console.log(Ext.getStore(this.storeId).proxy.reader.rawData);
```

Comment: Store loading is asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
   model: 'User',
   proxy: {
       type: 'ajax',
       url: '/users.json',
       reader: {
           type: 'json',
           root: 'users'
       }
   },
   autoLoad: true
});
```

The property "proxy" does not exist - try getProxy or whatever

```
getStore().getProxy().getReader().rawData;
```

[Sencha Documentation 4.2.2](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store)

Comment: not working ..`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getProxy' of undefined `

Comment: Than you don't have a proxy defined yet?

Comment: ` var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
     model: 'User',
     proxy: {
         type: 'ajax',
         url: '/users.json',
         reader: {
             type: 'json',
             root: 'users'
         }
     },
     autoLoad: true
 });`

Comment: @Poonam Bhatt : It is saying that `getStore()` returns undefined. What is `this` referring to? Can we see the code where that store definition resides?